# Let's get critical: Mar 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Sound Design Stack Exchange](http://sound.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://sound.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [If we recorded tracks at 48khz, and are mixing through an analog console, is there any benefit to printing the mix in 96khz instead of 48khz?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/26551/if-we-recorded-tracks-at-48khz-and-are-mixing-through-an-analog-console-is-the)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Fading Out Best Practices](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/26583/fading-out-best-practices)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [lightning / thunder offset](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/22226/lightning-thunder-offset)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What is the best/easiest way to fade a sound (beeping noise) in and out without the audience noticing that its gone?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/24624/what-is-the-best-easiest-way-to-fade-a-sound-beeping-noise-in-and-out-without)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How should you set your instrument levels prior to recording?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/26654/how-should-you-set-your-instrument-levels-prior-to-recording)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Creating Mech Sounds Similar to Gundam Wing](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/22163/creating-mech-sounds-similar-to-gundam-wing)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to record a cajon without it sounding terrible?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/24618/how-to-record-a-cajon-without-it-sounding-terrible)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to make recorded voice sound good](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/24923/how-to-make-recorded-voice-sound-good)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How do you do waves "at sea"?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/22261/how-do-you-do-waves-at-sea)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Is there a gadget that would convert the stereo speaker output into Bluetooth?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/26554/is-there-a-gadget-that-would-convert-the-stereo-speaker-output-into-bluetooth)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

Answer (score 1):

I am officially *cancelling* this self-review, because we've still got a bunch of migrations from AVP that didn't fit well pending rejection and ugh, the cleanup :)

Feel free to participate in this if you'd like, but the timing here is anything but opportune.